# Sitecore Commerce Demo Site not Rendered on Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, sitecore-commerce

I installed the Sitecore Commerce 9 update 1. I followed steps from this site

https://buoctrenmay.com/2018/03/24/step-by-step-guide-for-sitecore-xc9-update-1-installation-on-your-machine/

After successfully installed powershell script without errors, I tried to open storefront.local/ site and managed to see demo site. However, when I try to open Experience Editor I don't see items from the demo site, I just see empty Experience Editor. Check screenshots.

[image]

[image]

When I open storefront.local/ and do search, I get error page "There is no method 'FacetOn' on type 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions"
I assume that something is wrong. I think I did post installation steps correctly. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

That error message usually means that your SOLR indexes are paused. You can check their state using the sitecore powershell tools. You can also check the search log to see if there are any SOLR connection errors.

It's a super weird error, but when the indexes are paused Sitecore uses a normal collection for the IQueryable, which isn't supported by the FacetOn extensions method.

Comment: I checked search log but no errors there.

Comment: Did you check if your indexes were paused?

Comment: I solved the issue with solr indexes but my Experience Editor is still empty.